# error hibernate subselect org.hibernate.QueryException: aggregate function

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, hql

i have the next problem with my hql: org.hibernate.QueryException: aggregate function expected before ( in SELECT

The hlq is:

```
SELECT 
    t_res.resId , 
   ( SELECT COUNT(t_est_res.esrId) 
     FROM TstEstabResol AS t_est_res 
     WHERE t_est_res.resId=t_res.resId
   )  
FROM 
    TstResolucion AS t_res   
WHERE 
    t_res.resOculto=0
```

Can any tell me what is wrong, please????

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an AS on the sub query.

Try:

```
SELECT 
    t_res.resId , 
   ( SELECT COUNT(t_est_res.esrId) 
     FROM TstEstabResol t_est_res 
     WHERE t_est_res.resId=t_res.resId
   ) AS num_t_est_res
FROM 
    TstResolucion t_res   
WHERE 
    t_res.resOculto=0
```

Comment: Thank you @bradleyfitz but It continues with the same problem